# Opposing needs: soundproofing a door, constructing a cat door - can both be met?

Tags: doors, sound-proofing, pet-door

There is a door we would like to soundproof, or at least insulate phonically to the extent possible: it leads to a narrow open staircase leading to the attic, which is currently a somewhat creaky place, and will probably remain so to some small extent, in spite of our determined efforts.

The problem is that we also wish to install a cat door in the lower part of the doors. My architect says one cannot do both. Are there such a thing as a cat door that does not make sound insulation of the human door around it pointless?

(There are cat flaps that perform reasonably well in terms of heat insulation - do they also work for sound insulation? See https://www.thepetflap.com/passivhaus-pet-door/ .)

Comment: You could build a long kitty portico tunnel leading up to the cat door, on the hinge side of the door so it's least in the way. Then line the tunnel with carpet, towels, foam, etc to absorb the vast majority of waves than enter the open side of the tunnel.

Comment: @dandavis Right, I was thinking along the same lines, but wondered whether I was being silly. Is there something like that being produced (so that I don't have to pay a small fortune to a carpenter)?

Comment: I'd probably need to use foam and then a washable material - this is a tunnel that the cat will often go through after using the cat toilet.

Comment: Any possibility to add another door to create an "airlock" between the noisy part of the house and the quiet part?

Comment: @Huesmann No, not really. We looked at that possibility a long time ago, and had to discard it.

Answer (score 1):

I would expect the Petflap (first time I'm seeing it) would do a bit better simply because it has more mass than the typical cat door.On the other hand, I'm not sure one smallish opening will make that much difference either way.

Since sound can be conducted by the frame of the house, not just by the air of the stairwell, I'd try to mJe sure this was actually going to make a significant difference before investing much money in the project.

(How long have you been in the house? My experience is that after a while we learn to tune out most noise sources. I rarely notice the cat fountain I have running in the living room unless I'm actively paying attention to it or trying to record audio.)

Comment: I haven't lived in the house yet - we have just "playtested" it by walking around on it, talking loudly, and the like.

Comment: We have the library/music room downstairs, so blocking noise from upstairs does seem to be a need.

Comment: Personally I'd wait and see whether it's still a problem after you have a Housefull of furniture to diffuse and absorb sound and some practical experience of whether it's really a problem or not. At worst it means a few slightly noisy months, but it may save you the renovation cost. If you were setting up a recording studio I might feel otherwise.

Comment: Well, I am in the middle of a big renovation, so, in terms of labor costs and convenience, it makes sense to do now whatever can be done now.

Comment: May be. If you're convinced it's a good bet, go for it.